# Mesos Cgroup resource usage

Tags: mesos, marathon

I am building an autoscaling system using mesos and marathon. The scenario is, I want to autoscale a task, if the amount of memory allocated to it is consumed more than 80%. How do I find out the amount of memory used at a cgroup level?

Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the stastics for each task by hitting http://host:5051/monitor/statistics.json where host is mesos slave.

[This repo](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-autoscale) will give you an idea how to autoscale marathon applications.

Comment: However, worth mentioning, I did beat you to it!